# Splitting numbers between zeroes into separate lists in Python

Tags: python

I'm not getting anywhere with google, as I don't think I can formulate this into a search query well.

I have this list:

```
a = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 23.1, 23.1, ... , 23.1, 0.0, ... , 0.0, 34.5, ...,  34.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

I'd like to make it into this:

```
asplit = [[23.1], [34.5]]
```

EDIT:

So I've change the code in the example above. I have a list that has, let's say, 234 zeroes at the front, then the number 23.1 repeated 90 time, then a 987 zeroes, then 65 occurrences of 34.5, then 34 zeroes.

The number of non-zero unique values will vary, as will the count of each unique value, and the number of zeroes between each unique number will also vary. It is even possible that the numbers will not be unique, but that is highly unlikely and I'm prepared to make the assumption that they are.

I need to preserve the order in which the unique numbers occur.

Sorry for the vagueness of my initial question. I find it hard to explain, but I'm fairly sure the answer will be simple.

Comment: How about `zip(*[(x for x in a if x)]*2)`?

Comment: Could you give a more detailed description of your problem?  It's not quite clear how you want to form the result.  The solution suggested in the first comment assumes the result should consist of pairs of numbers, but there are other possible interpretations of your question.  It's also unclear what you tried, and what specifically poses a problem for you.

Comment: @vaultah Judging from the title of the question, I don't think that's what the OP wants, but I admit it's unclear.

Comment: So you want a list of single-element lists as return value?  Why not simply a list of numbers?  It's also still unclear what specifically is causing problems for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may achieve it using `set`. Since, order of number is to be preserved, you can do:

```
 >>> my_list = [23.1, 23.1, 23.1, 0.0, 0.0, 34.5,  34.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
 >>> seen = set()
 >>> seen_add = seen.add
 >>> [[x] for x in my_list if x and not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]
[[23.1], [34.5]]
```

Else, *if order was not necessary*, you can simply achieve it via:

```
>>> my_list = [23.1, 23.1, 23.1, 0.0, 0.0, 34.5,  34.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>>> map(lambda x: [x], set(x for x in my_list if x))
[[34.5], [23.1]]
```

Comment: OP states that _I need to preserve the order in which the unique numbers occur._

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 3):

To get the first elements of all consecutive runs of non-zero numbers in the list `a`, you can use

```
from itertools import groupby
result = [next(vals) for k, vals in groupby(a, bool) if k]
```

Edit: Code adapted to match the updated question.

Comment: OP asked for `[[23.1], [34.5]]` but this outputs `[23.1, 34.5]`

Comment: Easily fixed by using `[[next(vals)] for k, vals in itertools.groupby(a, bool) if k]` of course

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution for the original question:

```
import itertools

a = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 23.1, 23.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 34.5, 34.6, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
b = [list(x[1]) for x in itertools.groupby(a, lambda x: x == 0) if not x[0]]
print(b)
```

And here's the solution if you don't want to have duplicate elements in the sublists:

```
import itertools

a = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 23.1, 23.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 34.5, 34.6, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
b = [list(set(x[1])) for x in itertools.groupby(a, lambda x: x == 0) if not x[0]]
print(b)
```

Comment: OP asked for `[[23.1], [34.5]]` but this gives `[[23.1, 23.1, 23.1], [34.5, 34.5]]`

Comment: @FujiApple That's correct, I've edited the answer, I thought he wanted split the list without deleting duplicates

Comment: @SvenMarnach I see, FujiApple confused me and I thought I had misunderstood the question. Anyway, now I've provided both solutions

Answer (score 1):

another solution but without itertools
**EDIT:** As Op changed the question quite a bit, here another solution to fit OPs needs

```
# init the loop 
i = 0
asplit = []
last = None
while i < len(a)-1:
    # add non-zero number, that is new
    cand = a[i]
    if cand != last and cand != 0.0:
        last = cand
        asplit.append([last])
    i += 1
```